# matching data in a column of two worksheets in excel

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets designed something like the following.

1st worksheet

Product                  Priority
12345678                    1

2nd Worksheet

Product                  Replacement Priority
12345678                     2

I need to add a column to sheet 1 that indicates the new assigned priority from 2nd worksheet. Any suggestions? I have tried vlookup but cant seem to get anything going.

Comment: `vlookup` should work.

Comment: some screen shots and your attempt at Vlookup will make our comments more useful

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use index match. For the new column in sheet 1, use this formula. It searches for the product id on sheet 2 and outputs the corresponding priority. It's basically vlookup, but I like it better.

=INDEX([sheet 2 priority array],match([sheet 1 product id],[sheet 2 product id Array]))

Sheet 2 Priority Array - the entire range of new priorities in sheet 2
Sheet 1 Product ID - the lookup value, the corresponding product ID in the row of sheet 1
Sheet 2 Product ID Array - the entire range of product ids in sheet 2